# how to get text by range or offset in from element?

Tags: javascript, rust

- **Goal** When the user type something like `@` I want to get all the text that com after the `@` in order to build mention functionality from scratch without a package. Also, I want to do it i an oritigal way instead of slicing the text. For example there maybe something like `curr.get_text_content_at_range(0,10)`
- **Problem** When i tried the following method the line `console.log(text[i:f]);` does not return the correct text after the @ sign. so I hat to `i+2` and `f+2` like this `console.log(text[i+2:f+2]);`

```html
<p class="my_element" contenteditable="true"></p>
```

```rust
fn selection() -> Option<usize> {
    let sel = window().unwrap_throw().get_selection().unwrap().unwrap().get_range_at(0).unwrap().end_offset().unwrap();
    Some((sel + 2) as usize)
}
pub(crate) fn mention_handler(&mut self) {
    let mut curr: Option<Element> = None;
    let mut i: Option<usize> = None;

    let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::KeyboardEvent| {
        let range = window().unwrap_throw().get_selection().unwrap().unwrap().get_range_at(0).unwrap();
        curr = Some(range.common_ancestor_container().unwrap().parent_element().unwrap());
        if event.key() == "@" {
            i = Mention::selection();
        }

        if i != None{
            let text = &curr.clone().unwrap().text_content().unwrap();
            log_1(&format!("{:#?},{:#?}", i, Mention::selection()).into());
            log_1(&format!("{:#?}", &text[i.unwrap()..Mention::selection().unwrap()]).into());
        }

    }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);

    self.editor.add_event_listener_with_callback("keyup", closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref());
    closure.forget();
}
```

- Note

  - curr = curr html element
  - f    = final value
  - f    = initial value

Comment: Your code has a number of syntax errors. Can you post the actual code you tried?

Comment: What programming language did you use in the second code snippet?

Comment: @abubakarutar`rust`